# Dictionary foreach KeyValuePair mystery

Tags: c#

Take this little piece of code

```
        NWN2GameAreaDictionary areaDictionary = app.Module.Areas;

        IEnumerator enumerator = areaDictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        MessageBox.Show(enumerator.Current.GetType().Name);

        enumerator = areaDictionary.Keys.GetEnumerator();
        enumerator.MoveNext();
        MessageBox.Show(enumerator.Current.GetType().Name);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, NWN2GameArea> entry in areaDictionary)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(entry.Key);
            MessageBox.Show(entry.Value.Name);
        }
```

The NWN2GameAreaDictionary inherits all the way from IDictionary

```
public class NWN2GameAreaDictionary : OEIDictionaryWithEvents
public abstract class OEIDictionaryWithEvents : DictionaryBase
public abstract class DictionaryBase : IDictionary, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

When I run that code I get an output for the first MessageBox and second one, respectivly being: NWN2GameArea and string.  So any sane normal person would assume the foreach loop would work ... yet

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Why would that be .... so I tried with some other stuff and wanted to know the type of Keys and Values and I get KeyCollection and ValueCollection.  Yet when I want to cast to those types ... the compiler just states, hey buddy these types DO NOT EXIST .... aaargh ... this language is getting an exercise in frustration ... I should just stick to java.

can anyone give me an explaination for this behaviour ?

Comment: try to learn how generics works before blame the language

Comment: Believe me I know how generics work ... I deal with them daily in my JAVA career.  However I did assume that every collection in C# was generic as well.  I learned it is not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DictionaryBase` is a non-generic type and the pairs returned from the enumerator are of type `DictionaryEntry` not the generic `KeyValuePair<string, NWN2GameArea>` type you are trying to cast to in your foreach loop.

You can change your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in areaDictionary)
{
    MessageBox.Show(entry.Key);
    MessageBox.Show(((NWN2GameArea)entry.Value).Name);
}
```

or you could inherit a generic collection instead.

Comment: Thanks Lee, so another thing learned today for me.  I'm an employed java dev for 6 to 7 years now, and for this hobby project I'm trying to write in C# and this language keeps surprising me in good and bad ways.  I would have imagined every collection would have been generic, seems that is not the case.  I'll have to be more carefull then figuring out what is generic and what is not.  All stackoverflow articles I read told me to use KeyValuePair.

Comment: @kenny - The classes in the `System.Collections` namespace are mostly legacy and have been replaced by those in `System.Collections.Generic`. You should use generic collections wherever possible in new code.